# Conditions for weak stationarity of AR(1)

Tags: time-series, stationarity

I don't know if it is my lack of understanding, or it is a misconception in time series analysis.

Here is a definition of an AR(1) process $\{X_t\}_{t \in T}$: $X_t = \omega + \psi X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$  where $\omega, \psi$ are constants. $\{e_t\}_{t \in T}$ is a white noise process $WN(0, \sigma^2)$, and $cov(e_t, X_s)= 0$ $(\forall t > s)$

I saw many people wrote that AR(1) is (weakly) stationary **if and only if** $|\psi| < 1$.

It does not seem to be right for me at all. It should be necessary to state the distribution of $X_t$ at a specific time t as anchor, or at least the first and second moments of $X_t$. Without that, I do not think we have enough information to conclude that $\{X_t\}_{t \in T}$ is stationary.

Here is what I have in my mind:

An AR(1) process  $\{X_t\}_{t \in T}$ is defined as follows: $X_t = \omega + \psi X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$  where $\omega, \psi$ are constants. $\{e_t\}_{t \in T}$ is a white noise process $WN(0, \sigma^2)$, and $cov(e_t, X_s)= 0$ $(\forall t > s)$.  $\{X_t\}_{t \in T}$ is said to be (weakly) stationary if and only if:

1. $|\psi| < 1$
2. $\mathbb{E}[X_t] = \frac{\omega}{1 - \psi}$
3. $\mathbb{V}[X_t] = \frac{\sigma^2}{1 - \psi^2}$
4. $cov[X_t, X_{t+h}] = \psi^{|h|}\mathbb{V}[X_t]$

Conditions 2 and 3 already imply 1.

**My first question**: Am I correct?

**My second question**: Regarding other definitions of AR(1) process, is it always true that they all assume $cov(e_t, X_s)= 0$ $(\forall t > s)$?

Comment: Hi: Conditions  2, 3 and 4 are implied by the definition of an AR(1) process so that's why they are often not included in the requirements for weak stationarity. 1 is the only condition that is not implied by the definition of an AR(1) process so that is why people often just state 1 for the weak stationarity requirement. But you have a point that 2, 3 and 4 don't make sense without 1 so it's probably not a bad thing to state them.  Technically, they aren't requirements but they don't make sense without 1 being TRUE.

Comment: and yes for the second question. but $cov(e_{s}, X_{t}) \neq 0$ for $t \gt s$.